# normal distribution question with percentages

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

**how a can i solve a normal distribution without the mean ?**
suppose a truck of river sand delivered by a company has normal distribution with a standard deviationof 100kg.if 20% of loads are at least 22 tonnes what is the probability that we get at least 20 tonnes of sand froma delivery?

Comment: Intuitively, I would say you must know the mean average (expected amount) of tons per truck in order to solve this question.

Comment: If the information in the question is exact then you can calculate the mean from the information given.  The answer will be high given that the difference between $22$ and $20$ is $10$ standard deviations.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- For a standard normal distribution with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$, at what value is $20\%$ of the distribution above that value.
- How many standard deviations above the mean does that represent?
- If the standard deviation were $0.1$ then how far below $22$ would the mean be?
- What is the probability of at least $20$ given that calculated mean and a standard deviation of $0.1$?

Answer (score 0):

Find the $z$ value of a normal distribution with stdev=100 at $0.2$.

$z_{0.2}*100kg + \mu = 22$

... that gives you $\mu$.

$z_{x}*100kg + \mu = 20$

... find $x$ to solve.